# How do you extend a view from a package in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vendor

So i integrated this package to my application, https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit and this package has its own view and i want to modify the views like the create.blade.php,.. how would i do this appropriately?

because my current solutions is just to copy the view from the package change the return view('create'); in my controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will notice many packages include in its instalation proccess this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

What it does behind the scenes is it looks for all package's service providers instructions in order to figure out it anything should be "published" (meaning copying from vendor folder to config/, views/ etc)

I looked at your package's service provider:
https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/blob/0.2/src/TicketitServiceProvider.php and from line 179 to 182, the package seems to have the correct "publish" instructions.

Which means probably that the documentation skiped this part.

So, you should just basically hit the command php artisan vendor:publish and it will copy views, translations, public and migrations folder to your own apps folders.

Then you will see inside your resources/views a vendor folder, which will now have the ticketit views inside it.

Laravel figure it out when you say "view('ticketit.form.index')" and it will first look inside your own resources folder, if it don't find the content, it will try to look inside the package's folder.

For more, read the docs:https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#views

Comment: so meaning if the package don't have proper publish instructions the only way to extend the views are to copy and paste it?

Comment: I guess that would work. Or maybe making a PR and editing the library?! :p

Answer (score 3):

Just to add one more thing, you can choose which type of resources to publish by using the tags for the publish command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Kordy\Ticketit\TicketitServiceProvider" --tag="views"
```

*Publish only ticketit views (destination: `base_path/resources/views/vendor/ticketit`)*

If for any reason, found extending views is not enough and want to extend functionalities or controllers themselves, [ticketit allows using of custom routes file](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/wiki/Custom-routes-and-customizing-Ticketit-functions), you can use that to point to your own custom controllers.

---

**Other supported vendor publish tags:**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Kordy\Ticketit\TicketitServiceProvider" --tag="lang"
```

*Publish only ticketit translation files (destination: `base_path/resources/lang/vendor/ticketit`)*

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Kordy\Ticketit\TicketitServiceProvider" --tag="db"
```

*Publish only ticketit migration files (destination: `base_path/database/migrations`)*

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Kordy\Ticketit\TicketitServiceProvider" --tag="public"
```

*Publish only ticketit web resources (js, css, ..) files (destination: `public_path/vendor/ticketit`)*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue the solution is Laravel default convention, as shown in documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#views (publishing views topic)

In short, you need to use the resource path as:

`'__DIR__.'/path/to/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/view_namespace)'`

where view_namespace is the second parameter inside your `loadViewsFrom` method.

So given the file: https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/blob/0.2/src/TicketitServiceProvider.php

If line 102 is  `$this->loadViewsFrom($viewsDirectory, 'ticketit');`

Line 103 should be:

`$this->publishes([$viewsDirectory => base_path('views/vendor/ticketit')], 'views');`